# Import System Modules in a Conda Environment

Tags: anaconda, conda, pytorch

I have installed caffe and pytorch0.3 in my system path(environment), and there is a project which only works under caffe and history version of pytorch0.2. To solve that I install pytorch0.2 in a Conda environment and I wonder if there is any way can save me from installing a caffe again in this conda environment.

In other words, can I use pytorch0.2 in this Conda environment meanwhile import the system caffe? and how?

Answer (score 1):

Activate your environment and try the following

```
conda install package-name --offline
```

Also, in case you wish to clone the root or some other environment to a conda environment, you can use -- clone. For instance, when you wish to clone the root -

```
conda create -n pytorch_02 --clone root
```